# Does Gayatri Mantra affect physical reality?

Tags: mantras, gayatri-mantra

As some background I grew up in a Hindu household but Hinduism never resonated with me.

As an adult I was looking to improve my Anxiety disorder and found meditation to be very powerful. I was unsure about Gods, prayers etc. But I knew from experience and science that meditation works. I decided to experiment with 108 gayatri mantra before meditation daily. The 108 gayatri puts me into a really deep meditation. I decided to try 1008 gayatri and I find that it effects my physical body and mind quite a bit. I even found a study showing how it improves neurochemistry of the human brain.

I was wondering if Gayatri Mantra specifically, or mantras in general affect the physical reality? Does Gayatri mantra change reality on a metaphysical level? And where in the Vedas does it state this?

What was the purpose and use of mantras in Vedic times? What I found online:

> In Hinduism, suggests Alper,[41] the function of mantras shifted from the quotidian to redemptive. In other words,[42] in Vedic times, mantras were recited a practical, quotidian goal as intention, such as requesting a deity's help in the discovery of lost cattle, cure of illness, succeeding in competitive sport or journey away from home. The literal translation of Vedic mantras suggests that the function of mantra, in these cases, was to cope with the uncertainties and dilemmas of daily life. In a later period of Hinduism,[43] mantras were recited with a transcendental redemptive goal as intention, such as escape from the cycle of life and rebirth, forgiveness for bad karma, and experiencing a spiritual connection with the god. The function of mantras, in these cases, was to cope with the human condition as a whole.

Comment: "But I knew from experience and science that meditation works" meditation is different from reciting mantra's. I think you conflate the two.

Comment: I don't have enough details to justify a full answer, but if you're looking at physical benefits of sounds from a science perspective you might want to look at the effect of vibrations on wound healing (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC9859045/). Cats have been shown to purr at frequencies that aid healing (https://pubs.aip.org/asa/jasa/article/110/5_Supplement/2666/550913/The-felid-purr-A-healing-mechanism). The vagus nerve can also be stimulated or affected by sound through humming or singing, or from external sources (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6790306/)

Answer (score 5):

The Sanskrit vowels are placed in such manner that speaking them vocally enhances and activates the entire mouth and the organs involved in producing the sound.

the neurological benefit of some vowels is true, take OM for an example
It is a combination of 3 vowels "A + U + M", when spoken as a singularity, A activates lower abdominal and stomach portion and speaking U activates chest and upper neck, while M activates the mind.
You can try it out on your own, A = brahmA , U = Vishnu , M= Shiva

The main philosophy is that most mantras were not created but rather found by rishis in meditation, as the utterance of these specific words combined together produces specific rhythms which are good for soul and body.

Whether it affects your outer reality or not is still debatable, but it sure affects the inner being of the one chanting.

Reference: https://www.rudraksha-ratna.com/articles/Trijuti-Brahma-Vishnu-Mahesh
Further reading: https://upliftconnect.com/neuroscience-and-the-sanskrit-effect

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism Stack Exchange! Could you add authentic source for this statement of yours: "A = brahmA , U= Vishnu , M= Shiva" ?

Comment: https://www.rudraksha-ratna.com/articles/Trijuti-Brahma-Vishnu-Mahesh  , https://www.oshoworld.com/tantra_medi/otantra.asp?news_id=39

Comment: try to utter A = abdominal region is activated , signifying brahma as he is created, and human reproduction is used for birthing is situated there

Comment: U = Vishnu, preserves the universe, our lungs and heart preserve and makes sure the body is running smoothly, and transfer oxygen to entire body , signifying the role of Vishnu

Comment: Thanks! I have updated your answer with the link

Comment: M = Mahadev, signifying Brain, he is creater and destroyer both, if one has good controll over his mind, either he can be distructive or give great gifts to world. Hence this vowel helps in activating the mind and control it

Comment: Since you're new to this site, you may want to check chatroom for general discussion on dharma: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15189/hinduism

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism Stack Exchange. We insist on citing some authentic sources rather than blogs. See "Sources and Citations" section of [FAQ](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/478/277)